# Cannot get horizontally-listed ul to overflow horizontally (and scroll)

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm trying to get an unordered list to be listed out horizontally (accomplished with float:left), but it refuses to overflow horizontally. Instead, it automatically overflows in the next line (furthermore, even with overflow-y:none, it creates a vertical scrollbar automatically. Any ideas?

```
<style type="text/css">
    ul {
        height:15px;
        width:400px;
        overflow-y:none;
        overflow-x:auto;
    }

    li {
        float:left;
    }

</style>

<body>
    <div>
        <ul id="someList">
            <li>element 1</li>
            <li>element 2</li>
            <li>element 3</li>
            <li>element 4</li>
            <li>element 5</li>
            <li>element 6</li>
            <li>element 7</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can I ask in what context do you want a horizontal scroll bar on an unordered list?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this should be it:

http://jsfiddle.net/Uyc8d/

I've switched to using `display: inline-block` (instead of `float: left`), and I'm using `white-space: nowrap` to prevent wrapping.

```
ul {
    width: 400px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    background: #ccc;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;

    /* if you need ie7 support */
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
}
```

Comment: for the life of me... I couldn't remember the name of this css attribute. Thank you Sr.

Comment: Ensure there is **NO FLOAT** and this will work great. Also, `overflow-x: auto;` is a better choice on dynamic lists, that way there is no bar in view unless necessary.